# Check iPhone factory information

Tags: iphone, unlock

This is my first question here. I am going to buy a new iPhone 6s and got confused. In my country we do not have any Apple authorised seller. So I have to buy from any mobile shop. I searched Google but not found exactly what I look for. Here is my simple question:

How can I see factory information of my iPhone?

As some criminals may buy a locked iPhone from Apple cheaply and illegally unlock it, then tell me that it is an original unlocked iPhone. I heard of some techniques of unlocking that we can do everything after illegally unlocking. This is why I want to see original data by serial/IMEI so that I can be sure that the iPhone was sold unlocked from Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide any carrier unlock status. You need to be vigilant and protect yourself from a buyer by using an escrow agent or other payment arrangement / pre-sale inspection. Furthermore, the original Serial Number and IMEI can be unreliable if there was a service event, error in several databases, etc... It's better to have in writing what you are purchasing and the ability to return the goods if you can't inspect them before you pay.

As for iCloud activation lock, Apple has a nice page to check that before you commit to a potential purchase:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365

Scroll down to the section titled "**How do I check for Activation Lock before purchasing a used device?**" and the link for that is:

- https://icloud.com/activationlock

You need to contact a cellular carrier to clear the IMEI so I would expect that the carrier you will be paying for service would help you out unless they make their money selling hardware and you are cutting them out of their compensation by buying a used device.